# How do I figure out what is wrong with my code when the output is correct?

Tags: c, runtime-error

I am new to programming and I am trying to solve 929-Number Maze on UVA-online judge and I wrote this code and it is working fine in code blocks but when I submit this code on uva-online judge it shows Runtime error and I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int min(int x, int y);

int minCost(int **cost, int m, int n) {
    int i, j;
    int tc[m][n];

    tc[0][0] = cost[0][0];

    for (i = 1; i < m; i++) {
        tc[i][0] = tc[i - 1][0] + cost[i][0];
    }
    for (j = 1; j < n; j++) {
        tc[0][j] = tc[0][j - 1] + cost[0][j];
    }
    for (i = 1; i < m; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < n; j++) {
            tc[i][j] = min(tc[i - 1][j], tc[i][j - 1]) + cost[i][j];
        }
    }
    return tc[m - 1][n - 1];
}

int min(int x, int y) {
    if (x < y)
        return x;
    else
        return y;
}

int main() {
    int t, a, b, M, N, k;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while (t--) {
        scanf("%d", &M);
        scanf("%d", &N);
        int **c = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int*) * M);
        for (k = 0; k < N; k++)
            *(c + k) = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * M);

        for (a = 0; a < M; a++) {
            for (b = 0; b < N; b++) {
                scanf("%d", &c[a][b]);
            }
        }
        int res = minCost(c, M, N);
        printf("%d", res);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## input:

```
2
4
5
0 3 1 2 9
7 3 4 9 9
1 7 5 5 3
2 3 4 2 5
1
6
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

## output:

```
24
15
```

Comment: show us the problem parameters

Comment: `for( k =0 ; k <N;k++)
    *(c+k) = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*M);` --> `for( k =0 ; k <M;k++)
    *(c+k) = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*N);`

Comment: `int tc[m][n];` might be big on the stack.

Comment: [929 - Number Maze](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=870)

Comment: I'd worry about all the calls to `malloc()` without a call to `free()` in sight.

Comment: Your outputs are not separated by newlines, either.  That will cause problems when you've fixed the memory issues.

Comment: The use of `scanf` without checking the return value is a problem. However, I have no idea whether the "online judge" uses test cases with invalid input

Comment: @4386427: the online judges give well-formed inputs; you can skimp on error processing and get away with it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I see... kind of a poor judge. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @4386427: the online judges are looking at the cleverness of your algorithms, not the sophistication of your I/o handling.  It means that being good at their problems does not show you can solve 'real world' programming issues, where faulty input data is a common occurrence. But they wouldn't claim that's what they're measuring.  It would complicate their analysis (and problem specification) if they needed to deal with erroneous inputs.

Answer (score 1):

```
*(c+k) = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*N);
```

This should be `N`

Answer (score 1):

One issue is in

```
*(c+k) = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*M);
```

It should be

```
*(c+k) = malloc(sizeof(int)*N);  //N instead of M
```

Comment: thanks no more runtime error but it says wrong answer this time. and still this code is working fine in codeblocks and ideone. it passes the given test cases.

Comment: @Mank99999: your output from your code is all on one line with no spaces between answers, but it should be on multiple lines, one answer per line.

Comment: @Mank99999: there is another error in this initialization loop. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of programming.

A careful code review shows this error:

The initialization loop is incorrect in both the loop test and the `malloc` argument, it should read:

```
    for (k = 0; k < M; k++) {
        c[k] = malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
    }
```

As posted, your program invokes undefined behavior. It may produce the expected results by chance (as observed on your system), but it may also produce a runtime error when you access the arrays beyond the allocated size (as observed on the uva-online judge site).